# What's the deal with Influence Gain in Dungeon Siege 3?

Tags: dungeon-siege-3

I'm curious about what kind of benefits there are for having high influence over your party members in Dungeon Siege 3. Certain decisions I make in game cause an 'influence gain' with my comrades. Now, I have a feel for which options will give my teammates that boost so I've been structuring my decision making in order to meet their standards. I'm wondering if it is worth it for me to continuing playing this way. I found this bit of information in the help topics under the 'Companions' tab:

'Companions are party members that will help you throughout your journey. As you travel with your companions, you will gain influence with them, unlocking special bonuses.'

There's no explanation given beyond that. So my question is - what kind of special bonuses can I expect?

Comment: I'm also trying to understand the answer to this question. Started playing Dungeon Siege 3 a few days ago, but still haven't figured it out (have done multiple searches as well). It might be awhile before anyone actually figures it out. At first I thought it would be similar to the Dragon Age series where "gaining influence" allows you to open up special perks with individual characters, such as romantic options and the like, but I haven't heard anything about that so I don't know.

Comment: I love the idea of romantic options. I'm playing as Katarina and I have Lucas as my secondary party member so that would work out well. I guess we'll just have to see.

Comment: Except that Lucas and Katarina are brother and sister...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gaining influence with allies will go towards earning deeds with each: you receive a deed for earning 25%, 50%, and 75% influence with a specific ally.

At each of these milestones, you gain a number of points in a specific attribute associated with an ally:

- Lucas: Stamina
- Anjali: Attack
- Katarina: Agility
- Reinhart: Will

- 25% influence: 2 points
- 50% influence: 3 points
- 75% influence: 5 points

These gains are cumulative, so you can gain a maximum of 10 points in an attribute this way.

Answer (score 1):

I've began playing it this week-end. So I did not benefit influence for the moment, but from my experiences reputation systems are used to unlock special parts of scenarios. Maybe you will have gain on a justice trial since they will testify for you. Maybe they will ask you for a special quest because they trust you, or maybe they will give your their father magic ring... who knows.

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering if it's something quest related (like special quests that are only unlocked at certain influence levels), story driven (like where the plot is changed because of influence level), or if it's stat based. I'm so curious!

Answer (score 0):

Maximum influence awards deeds, which grant you a stat boost.

Maybe it should be called "trust" rather than "influence"; may this help you make your choice.

Comment: Telling people to "Google it" is Not Done. It's more of a "when we're done here, this question should be a first-page Google result" deal.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing for two days so far and all I've managed to figure out is that it says 
"Deed Accomplished" or something and you get an ability bonus.

As for those purple dots next to your avatar pic -- its seems that more deeds you do, the more dots you get.